# How can I insert a new tag into a BeautifulSoup object?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to get my head around html construction with BS.

I'm trying to insert a new tag:

```
self.new_soup.body.insert(3, """<div id="file_history"></div>""")
```

when I check the result, I get:

```
&lt;div id="file_histor"y&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

So I'm inserting a string that being sanitised for websafe html..

What I expect to see is:

```
<div id="file_history"></div>
```

How do I insert a new `div` tag in position 3 with the id `file_history`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the factory method to create new elements:

```
new_tag = self.new_soup.new_tag('div', id='file_history')
```

and insert it:

```
self.new_soup.body.insert(3, new_tag)
```

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks. Its a two step process, and I was trying to cheat. Appreciated.

Answer (score 54):

See the documentation on [how to append a tag](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<b></b>")
original_tag = soup.b

new_tag = soup.new_tag("a", href="http://www.example.com")
original_tag.append(new_tag)
original_tag
# <b><a href="http://www.example.com"></a></b>

new_tag.string = "Link text."
original_tag
# <b><a href="http://www.example.com">Link text.</a></b>
```

Answer (score 16):

Other answers are straight off from the documentation. Here is the shortcut:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

temp_soup = BeautifulSoup('<div id="file_history"></div>')
# BeautifulSoup automatically add <html> and <body> tags
# There is only one 'div' tag, so it's the only member in the 'contents' list
div_tag = temp_soup.html.body.contents[0]
# Or more simply
div_tag = temp_soup.html.body.div
your_new_soup.body.insert(3, div_tag)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### An Example Of How To Do This Inside A Specific Tag Area Such As `<head>`

The good answers herein led me to the documentation to learn more about how to handle my specific needs.

I hope this example helps some others that come to this question / answers to see the bigger picture.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


orig_html = """<html>
  <head></head>
  <body><h1>Some Body</h1></body>
</html>
"""

orig_soup = BeautifulSoup(orig_html, "html5lib")
# Find <head> area first
head = orig_soup.find("head")

# Just showing that my <head> initially had NO content
print("Head Contents:")
print(f'"{head.contents}"')
print()

# Append content to <head> using the soup.new_tag method
new_style_tag = orig_soup.new_tag(
    "link", href="style.css", rel="stylesheet", type="text/css"
)
head.append(new_style_tag)

# Verify that <head> now as the new contents
print("Head Contents:")
print(f'"{head.contents}"')
print()

new_html_text = orig_soup.prettify()

# Check how it appears in the HTML
print(new_html_text)
```

And here is the output of the above script.

```bash
Head Contents:
"[]"

Head Contents:
"[<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>]"

<html>
 <head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
 <body><h1>Some Body</h1></body>
</html>
```