# How to add li tag using beautiful soup in python

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-lists

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>tweetDisplayName</li>
            </br>
            <li>Link:<a href="tweetLink">tweetLink</a></li>
            </br>
        </ul>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
""")
```

I need to add `li` tag after `tweetDisplayName` using `BeautifulSoup` in python. Does anyone know about it?

Comment: duplicated, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356014/how-can-i-insert-a-new-tag-into-a-beautifulsoup-object

Answer (score 0):

```
li_new = soup.new_tag("li")
li_new['class'] = 'cls'
li_new.append("content")
li_element = soup.find_all('li', text='tweetDisplayName')[0]
li_element.insert_after(li_new)
```