# Want to add some line at particular location in html code

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parser

I want to add some line of code in html code at some particular location. I want to know which library will be more helpful BeautifulSoup or html parser?
I just to want to add a new line and then write a line of code there. Please help out. 
I need recommendation to automate a simple process.

Comment: From Review: Unfortunately [questions asking for: libraries, tools, or other off-site resource are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you are referring to is adding a html element/tag to some html.

Beautiful soup can do what you need relatively simply.

Overview of how in this thread.

[How can I insert a new tag into a BeautifulSoup object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356014/how-can-i-insert-a-new-tag-into-a-beautifulsoup-object)