# Inserting tag into html with beautifulsoup with values already existing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags

I'm building off of the example [How can I insert a new tag into a BeautifulSoup object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356014/how-can-i-insert-a-new-tag-into-a-beautifulsoup-object).

```
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a = [['1/2/2014', 'a', '6', 'z1'],
     ['1/2/2014', 'a', '3', 'z1'],
     ['1/3/2014', 'c', '1', 'x3'],
     ]
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(a[1:], columns=a[0])
soup = BeautifulSoup(df.to_html(header=False), 'lxml')

original_tag = soup.find_all('td')[4]
new_tag = soup.new_tag('FONT', COLOR='white')
original_tag.append(new_tag)
print(soup)
```

As you can see. `1/3/2014` is outside of the tag `<FONT COLOR>`. I need the `<FONT COLOR>` tag to be wrapped around `1/3/2014`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`wrap`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#wrap) on the contents of the required tag.

```
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a = [['1/2/2014', 'a', '6', 'z1'],
     ['1/2/2014', 'a', '3', 'z1'],
     ['1/3/2014', 'c', '1', 'x3']]
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(a[1:], columns=a[0])
soup = BeautifulSoup(df.to_html(header=False), 'lxml')

original_tag = soup.find_all('td')[4]
new_tag = soup.new_tag('FONT', COLOR='white')
original_tag.contents[0].wrap(new_tag)
print(soup)
```