# BeautifulSoup4 : Need to add inverse paragraphs tags to separate a field into two paragraphs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Currently, there is this one header tag which has its contents attached to it. I need to separate the header from its content by maintaining them in separate paragraph tags.

```
block_tag = <p>1.1 <u>Header Information</u>.  Content of the header with multiple lines</p>

type(block_tag)
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

Header is expected to be enclosed in either `<b>` or `<u>` tags

Expected result:

```
block_tag
<p>1.1 <u>Header Information</u>.</p><p>  Content of the header with multiple lines</p>
```

So far I have tried adding the paragraph tags by using -

new_tag("p") creates `<p></p>` . Inverse tags are needed `<\p><p>`

Approach-1

```
para_tag = soup.new_tag("p")
block_tag.insert(2,para_tag)
block_tag
<p>1.1 <u>Header Information</u>. <p></p> Content of the header with multiple lines</p>
```

Approach-2

```
block_tag.insert(2,"<\p><p>")
block_tag
<p>1.1 <u>Header Information</u>&lt;\p&gt;&lt;p&gt;.  Content of the header with multiple lines</p>
```

Thank you

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356014/how-can-i-insert-a-new-tag-into-a-beautifulsoup-object

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, that is not what I am looking for. I need to add inverse tags . As in </p><p> and not the usual <p></p>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the remaining contents after header and *[wrap](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#wrap)* it inside a new `p` tag. Then *[extract](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract)* it from the original tag and [*insert_after*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after) original tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<p>1.1 <u>Header Information</u>.  Content of the header with multiple lines</p>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
block_tag=soup.find('p')
remaining=block_tag.contents[-1]
new_tag=remaining.wrap(soup.new_tag("p"))
block_tag.insert_after(new_tag.extract())
print(soup)
```

Outputs:

```
<p>1.1 <u>Header Information</u></p><p>.  Content of the header with multiple lines</p>
```

Almost perfect except for the *full stop*.

Note:
I am not sure exactly what the `Content of the header with multiple lines` is, but don't treat this as an exact answer. You may have to improvise on this.